# Mobile web Programming ide with simulator

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, web

Im done creating an android application and already published it on google play. What i want now is to create a website for mobile. I think i will use PHP,HTML5,CSS and some javascript. But i dont know what IDE should i use. Creating a website in desktop is easy cause you can view it in your firefox. But how about mobile? is there a **simulator** to run a php file just like wamp?  I want to run my website through localhost first before uploading it in the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view and test on actual devices without "uploading it in the net".

To do this, configure the server on your development computer to serve on your local IP address (it will probably start with 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x), and make sure your phone or mobile device is on the same wireless network as the computer (this will work well on home networks, but may not work on managed corporate networks).

You will be able to test the website served from your computer to your phone without opening it up to the internet by typing your computer's IP address (possibly with the addition of a port number) directly into the browser on the phone.

If want, I'd recommend reading up on [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and IP addresses to understand what you're doing here, but basically your computer has an IP address, which is 4 numbers - probably looks like 192.168.x.x - which is used to identify it on the network.  "Localhost" is essentially a nickname / shortcut for "me" (the same way that "google.com" is the nickname / shortcut for the IP address of a server at Google).

To find the address for your computer, open a terminal (using run => cmd) and type

```
ifconfig /all
```

Look for the line that looks like:

```
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Depending on what software you're using and how it's configured, you may be able to just go directly to 192.168.x.x (replace with your actual address) on the browser on your phone.

If that doesn't work, there's a change that you will have to configure your web-server to accept connections which aren't coming from the same computer.  The readme / configuration documentation for whatever software you're using (e.g. Apache) should have advice on how to do that.

Comment: Im using windows xp. What server? is that the localhost? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here Try this

http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/